# Error on activating Publishing Feature SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, feature, publishing

I am working with SharePoint 2010. I need to activate SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure Feature under Site Administration>Site Collection features. But when I try to activate this feature I get the following error.

**The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.**

Source Error:

Could you please help me on this.

Kind Regards
Vivek B

Comment: Are you using an account with the right permissions? To me, nine times out of ten, when things won't get activated it has something to do with the permissions of the account I'm using.

Comment: Ok I got it done. What I did was I changed my site's application pool in IIS to Central Admin's application pool. Activated the feature and revert back the application pool to my site's own.And I was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it done. What I did was I changed my site's application pool in IIS to Central Admin's application pool. Activated the feature and revert back the application pool to my site's own.And I was done.